# Utility-Like Activity - SensorManager

Tags: java, android

I was hoping to implement a `SensorManager` class that could handle everything sensor-related but this obviously requires that I launch a new activity.

I was not looking to do this - just run the computations.  Is the best way to handle this with a service, can you call activity methods from a service?

Comment: if your method is static you can call the activity method from service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely possible to create a class - that is not an Activity - managing the sensors. You are right about the fact that, in order to "subscribe" to a sensor, you need a SensorManager. But any class can instantiate a SensorManager.

You could imagine a class "mySensorClass" beginning like this (imagine you want to collect data from the accelerometer):

```
public class mySensorClass implements SensorEventListener {
   public static final String TAG = "mySensorClass";

   private SensorManager mSensorManager;
   private Sensor mAccelerometer;

[...]
```

Then, in the constructor, you would instantiate the SensorManager and register to it:

```
public DeviceOrientation(Context context) {
   mSensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
   mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

   mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}
```

And finally, you would store the data you receive from the accelerometer in a class variable by using the method:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) { ... }
```

Eventually, your activity would simply have to create an instance of "mySensorClass" and could get the last measure from the accelerometer.